# A large number of alternate definitions of almost sure convergence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, almost-everywhere

So , after posting a large number of questions on this **Math.SE** and **Stats.SE** , I have finally compiled a set of alterantive definitions of almost sure convergence. They are

> $$X_n\xrightarrow{a.s.} X\\\Longleftrightarrow \Bbb{P}(\omega \ : \ X_n(\omega)\to X(\omega)\text{ as }n\to \infty)=1\\\Longleftrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}\Bbb{P}(\omega \ :\ \sup_{k>n}|X_k(\omega)-X(\omega)|>\epsilon)=0\ \ \forall \epsilon>0\\\Longleftrightarrow \Bbb{P}(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup_{k=n}^{\infty} \{ |X_k - X| > \epsilon \}) = 0\ \  \forall \epsilon>0$$

Are all these correct?

Specifically what happens when $X_n(\omega)\to X$ is replaced be $X_n(\omega)= X$ in the second definition (OR am I makinga fundamental mistake)?

Comment: All the equivalence seems fine to me. Also, when you replace $X_n \to X$ by $X_n = X$, what you get is a sequence which is eventually constant $\Bbb{P}$-a.s.

Comment: In the second line you want to write $X(\omega)$, not just plain $X$.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Thanks for that!